# Possible to restrict network camera access using URL key instead of http authorization?

Tags: security, network-camera

I own a few Axis network cameras, and all of the cameras implement an optional user-group security system with usernames and passwords.  I require a username and password to be entered in order to view the camera's Live View video feed over the internet.

However, user accounts are cumbersome when many users are using the camera from many different locations.  I want to continue to restrict access from the anonymous public, but still require a token to authenticate approved camera viewers.

In web programming situations I implement a URL key as a GET variable to handle this situation.  Using a GET variable in the URL, only the URL link is required to view the camera.  No http auth username and password would be required.  But I do not believe Axis cameras allow uploading server scripts onto the camera's web server to process GET variables.  So I do not think this is possible.

Is it possible to require a GET variable or some type of key in the URL to restrict access to the Axis camera's Live View picture?  If this is not possible on an Axis camera, is there another camera which makes this possible?  I know I could accomplish this using a stand-alone camera server such as [Zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/), but I am looking for a solution in the camera by itself.

Comment: Why not just include the username / password in the url using the standard method?

Answer (score 1):

URL keys have the property of being part of the URL, and in turn becoming part of one's browsing history.

On the other hand, you can specify the HTTP credentials in the URL, and most browsers will erase them before logging the URL anywhere<sup>[citation needed]</sup>, so this is more secure and easier to implement. You could even create an account named just `user` or such.

```
http://user:pass@camera-addr/
```

Comment: I did not know http credentials could be placed in the URL like this - cool!  Unfortunatly [IE8 and greater](http://www.rojotek.com/blog/2008/05/19/http-authentication-in-a-url/) do not allow http auth in the URL.

Comment: The camera's site performs a redirect after the initial index page, and the http auth is not required until after the redirect.  I tried accessing the target of the redirect directly, using the http auth variables in the url, but the camera doesn't accept this.  So more troubleshooting required.